# PHP Form data not sending

Tags: php, forms

I wanted to add an input field, where the user can input a name for example and it would be added to the relevant table in the database. However i want to create a new action for this, so far i have the basic input fields and submit button with the following code:

```
public function action_mynewaction() {
     $this->auto_render = false;
     if ($this->request->is_ajax()) 
     {
     $stmt = DB::query(Database::INSERT, 'INSERT INTO `mytable` (`name`) VALUES (:Name)');
     $view = View :: factory('my/form/file_path');
     echo $view->render();
     }
    }
```

**This is my view file where the form is displayed**

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" class="myclass noSort">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>A</th>
         <th>B</th>
         <th>C</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
                <form action="" method="post">
                 <td>Add Name</td>
                 <td><input type="text" name="Name"></td>
                 <td><input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
             </tr>
          </tbody>
   </table>
```

But whenever i add in my

> $stmt->param(':Name', $_POST['name']);

part it doen't show me the input/form field at all?

**Doesn't display form/input field at all**

```
       public function action_mynewaction() {
          $post = $this->request->post();

          $stmt = DB::query(Database::INSERT, 'INSERT INTO `mytable` (`name`) VALUES (:Name)');
          $stmt->param(':Name', $_POST['name']);
          $stmt->execute();

          $view = View :: factory('my/form/file_path');
          echo $view->render();
   }
```

Comment: For reference, you cannot put `form` elements directly inside `tr` elements. The only valid children are `td` and `th`.

Comment: @BenM That's good as html standard, but it allows you to put form isn't it? =/

Comment: `<td><input type="submit" value="Submit">` closing `</td>` missing

Comment: @Goikiu Sorry? I don't understand your comment?

Comment: @Goikiu well that depends on the browser. Some will outright remove the tag, others move it further up / down the DOM tree. It's unexpected behavior and you should not code around it.

Answer (score 2):

forms data are case sensitive.

Into your html you have : `name="Name"` and you will retrieve data with `$_POST['Name']` that said if the "receiver" php page isn't the same as the one is sending put an "action" to the form.

Comment: Without an `action`, the `<form>` will just submit to the same page.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I didn't ever used that. Thanks for the info. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow name convention so that it can bind corresponding element to browser get method.

```
    public function action_mynewaction() {
          $post = $this->request->post();

          $stmt = DB::query(Database::INSERT, 'INSERT INTO `mytable` (`name`) VALUES (:Name)');
          $stmt->param(':Name', $_POST['Name']); /* replace 'name' with 'Name' */
          $stmt->execute();

          $view = View :: factory('my/form/file_path');
          echo $view->render();
   }
```